# How to redirect my Wordpress website hosted on AWS from http to https automatically?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, http, redirect, https

I have hosted my Wordpress website on Amazon Web Services (AWS) and when i browse my domain name directly without any "https" it takes me to "http://example.com" host each time. But when i try to access my website with "https://example.com" i can easily access my website with secured connection each time. I want to know why this is happening ? and how can i resolve this issue?

I just want to know why the browser is not automatically redirecting it from "http" to "https"  cause it is not possible to access the  secured site by typing "https" as prefix each time and by every user.

Comment: Are you using AWS load balancer? or which type of Load balancer?

Comment: yeah i am using calssic loadbalancer

Comment: There is no to add redirect on the classic load balancer, Application load balancer have this feature out of the box, either move to application LB or use Nginx on your Ec2 side for redirection.

Comment: hey i have just created an application lb can you suggest me hoe to link it to my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add redirection to application Load Balancer, do the following

- Select ALB
- Select HTTP listener
- Add rule like below one

[image]

or if you want to redirect different domain then use custom header

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A server has to support the HTTPS protocol with additional steps which is not something that comes up as a default in every application.
This includes issuing certificates, making sure the server can handle the protocol etc. This is one of the reasons why browsers do not automatically redirect from http (:80) to https (:443)

As you have verified, you already have those checks in place. Now you have multiple ways to get http to redirect to https automatically:

1. **Redirect from AWS ALB**: If you are using an Application Load Balancer, you can set a redirection rule right within ALB. With this you server will not be burdened with this task. To set it up follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/) guide.
2. **Web Server Redirect**: If you are using web server like NGINX or Apache, you can add redirection rule in the config file. Follow [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/redirect-http-to-https-nginx) and [this](https://www.tecmint.com/redirect-http-to-https-on-apache/) one for Apache. If you are using anything else a simple google search will get you what you have to do.
3. **Redirect via .htaccess**: If you are using Wordpress, there's a good chance you have access to the `.htaccess` file. You can add the following rule to it to enable redirection ([reference 1](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/), [reference 2](https://in.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-for-wordpress-on-linux-27904)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

4. **Redirect via Wordpress Plugins**: What is wordpress without it's plugins right ? There are many plugins just for this task like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/) or [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/).